# Is there a R function to remove columns that only have missing values?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have around more than 1000 columns in my data frame that only has NA values throughout. Is there a function in R which could remove columns that have NA values throughout?

Comment: Can't find a duplicate. Here's a **self promotion** comment: `mde::drop_na_if(airquality,sign="eq",percent_na=100)` There exist simpler ways like `complete.cases`,`drop_na`(`tidyr`), etc from [mde](https://www.github.com/Nelson-Gon/mde) that I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not one function but

```
df[,colSums(apply(df,2,is.na))<nrow(df)]
```

Comment: You can avoid `apply()` by using `df[colMeans(is.na(df)) != 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(NA, rep(1, 9)),
                b = rep(NA, 10))

d[vapply(d, function(x) all(!is.na(x)), logical(1))]
```

Comment: Why is `a` dropped?

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?